# Is the "life force" and the "breathing" the same thing?

Tags: papanca

I read the following comment on the internet:

> *A corpse has lost its life-force, hence a corpse, dead. A meditator has attainment would be free from disease, for the vibrant
>   internal-breath kept one healthy.*

Are there any suttas that distinguish between the life force and the breathing?

Comment: The comment wasn't about "breathing" but "internal-breath" which is Chinese -- the author of the comment said, "Indian called Prana, Chinese Xi".

Comment: So the author was talking about non-Buddhist things?

Comment: They were referring to what they know of Chinese Buddhism ... but, have also been reluctant to answer questions about that in the past -- saying for example that relevant translations into English don't exist.

Comment: An angel (deva) just appear to me and said the answer might be in MN 43.

Answer (score 0):

MN 44 defines the term "kāyasaṅkhārā" as the in & out breathing.

MN 43 says in the state of "cessation of perception & feeling" (*saññāvedayitanirodhaṃ*), which is compared to a corpse with life, the "*kāyasaṅkhārā*" ("breathing") ceases but heat (*usmā*) & life force/vitality (*āyusaṅkhārā*) remain.

> *When a mendicant has attained the cessation of perception and feeling, their physical, verbal, and mental processes have ceased and
>   stilled. But their vitality is not spent; their warmth is not
>   dissipated; and their faculties are very clear.*
>
> *Yo cāyaṃ bhikkhu saññāvedayitanirodhaṃ samāpanno tassapi kāyasaṅkhārā niruddhā paṭippassaddhā, vacīsaṅkhārā niruddhā paṭippassaddhā,
>   cittasaṅkhārā niruddhā paṭippassaddhā, āyu na parikkhīṇo, usmā
>   avūpasantā, indriyāni vippasannāni.*
>
> [*MN 43*](https://suttacentral.net/mn43/en/sujato)

It follows, at least in Pali Buddhism, it seems the “life force” & the “breathing” are not the same thing.

Comment: I would also say that life force and breathing are not the same. In retreats I have experienced states without breath and heartbeat and am still alive. Nice to have a scriptural reference now.

Comment: @Dhammadatu Question for you: Since kāyasaṅkhārā is defined as 'in- and out breathing', wouldn't this mean that kāyanupassana is 'watching the breath meditation' instead of watching physical phenomena (heat, smoothness etc)? What then would anapanasati refer to?

Comment: The word "kāya" in "kāyasaṅkhārā" refers to the physical body. The breathing is the sankhara (conditioner) of the physical body because the breathing conditions the health & life of the physical body. Similar, thinking is the "vacisankhara" because thinking condtions speech (vaci). Thinking and speech are not the same thing; just as breathing & body are not the same thing; yet the body & speech are dependent upon breathing & thinking.